# Sqlite PHP permission issue / writing to a different folder

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, permissions

I have two sites running off a single box that answers on different ip addresses.

Both of these sites have different root folders `/var/www/` and `/var/www2`.

`/var/www` contains the main site and a sqlite database.

`/var/www2` contains a few scripts that need to access that same db.

I have tried

```
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:/var/www/db.sqlite');
```

from the second site, but, I keep getting `File not found`, and in the logs I get

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,``
```

Both of these sites work fine when reading/writing to dbs in their own folder without the path.

Can anyone advise anything?

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194196/1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown). hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Well it is permission problem. Site1 http server runs under *site1* user and site2 under *site2 user*.

Possible solutions are:

1. Set 0666 (writable from everyone) permission to /var/www/db.sqlite which is pretty **not secure**
2. Set 0660 (owner + group writable) to sqlite, add both site users to same group and *chgrp* of db.sqlite to *your created group*.